# how to load pdf.worker.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

Browser: Chrome and I'm using XAMPP Local Host

I have problem with PDF.js. I just try to load pdf file, render it in canvas and then I want to use some Visual Char Recognition lib (like ocrad.js) to put info from pdf file to the table. (I want to load COC document from delivery and automaticly load delivered goods into database). I don't know if that's possible but I want to try. And PDF.js is the first issue I met.

Part of the code:

```
        <div class="preformarray">
            <canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
<script>
    pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "pdf/pdf.worker.js";
    var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument('pdf/19662.pdf');
    loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
        // you can now use *pdf* here
        pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
            // you can now use *page* here
            var scale = 1.5;
            var viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale, });

            var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.height = viewport.height;
            canvas.width = viewport.width;

            var renderContext = {
              canvasContext: context,
              viewport: viewport
            };
            page.render(renderContext);
        });
    });
</script>
```

pdf.worker.js file is stored in the same folder that pdf document "19662.pdf". And in the consol log I'm receving:
Warning: Setting up fake worker.  pdf.js:468
Warning: decodeScan - unexpected MCU data, current marker is: ffff  pdf.worker.js:1014

and I have no clue how I can deal with it. PDF.js files are from the latest release. JS is not my thing and this is more PHP project, so please help me with this.

Comment: did you get the solution ?

Comment: Unfortanetly no